# jQuery Mobile filter list including search on dividers

Tags: jquery, list, mobile, filter

I'm developing a list with some dividers between the items in jQuery Mobile. I've also place a search box using the property data-filter="true". However, the filter only applies to the list items, and not on the dividers, and want to have the possibility to filter by the divider content.

I have seen the exact behavior I want in [this post](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/listview-with-search-bar-search-filters-list-divider) at the JQM forum, which I can't repeat (I suppose due to jQuery version).

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem can be resolved with a couple of change in the **jQuery Mobile file**.

Look for the code about the **Filter** (around the **7320th line**), find the **for** statement and **remove** the following part of the code:

```
if ( item.is( "li:jqmData(role=list-divider)" ) ) {

    item.toggleClass( "ui-filter-hidequeue" , !childItems );

    // New bucket!

    childItems = false;

} else
```

This works with both jQuery Mobile 1.1.1 and jQuery Mobile 1.2.0 Alpha.

I suggest you to work with the **uncompressed version** for changing this.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant to say that you want to filter the divider's "children" based on the divider's content **in addition** to the individual *listitem* content, you'll want to use the *data-filtertext* option on each *listitem*. Put both the divider text and the listitem's text together in the string.

```
<ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true'>
  <li data-role="list-divider">Tallahassee</li>
  <li data-filtertext="Tallahassee Dog Et Al">Dog Et Al</li>
  <li data-filtertext="Tallahassee Jim and Milts">Jim and Milts</li>
  <li data-role="list-divider">Atlanta</li>
  <li data-filtertext="Atlanta The Varsity">The Varsity</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, that i solved with JQM 1.4.2 by using the data-filtertext attribute to force list items to match with their wrapping list-divider text when filtering.

```
<form class="ui-filterable">
    <input id="filterBasic-input" data-type="search">
</form>

<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="c" data-input="#filterBasic-input" data-filter-theme="a" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Filtrer..." data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="list-divider" >
        Countries
    </li>

    <li data-filtertext="Countries">
        France
    </li>

    <li data-filtertext="Countries">
        England
    </li>

    <li data-filtertext="Countries">
        Cameroon
    </li>

    <li data-role="list-divider" >
        Fruits
    </li>

    <li data-filtertext="Fruits">
        Orange
    </li>

    <li data-filtertext="Fruits">
        Mango
    </li>

    <li data-filtertext="Fruits">
        Pineapple
    </li>

</ul>
```

Hope it helps!